# How to set separate log file to log 400 errors in nginx 1.4.7

Tags: nginx

I know , I can't use if condition in access_log in ngninx 1.4.7. Is there other way?

```
   listen       80 default_server;
    access_log  /log/nginx/access.log ;
  # access_log off;
```

........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is not to use antique version of nginx and upgrade.